# use selectedvalue in row context calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

this is a hard question, I have a filter on a standalone table (not connected to tables in my model) I need to retrieve the value from the filter, and calculate a calculated column on another table.

let say that the filter has {selected value} from Table A
I need this selected value to compute this formula:
newColumn = IF( TableB:colA = {selected value} then "caseA"
ELSE IF(TableB:colB = {selected value} then "caseB"
ELSE "caseElse"

the problem is that in a row context I haven't access to the filter context, so the formula SELECTEDFILTER give me back blank!

How do I compute this?
many thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use selections from the visuals (like slicer) to calculate a column?

Comment: In a calculated column I need to retrieved the selected value in a slicer

Comment: That is not possible. Calculated columns are static data, they are no different from the  source data you import. If you need responsiveness to slicers, it must be a measure.

Comment: Is there any way to compute this using another formula, like CONCATENATEX?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment about CONCATINATEX. If you write a measure, you can do whatever you need. If you want a calculated column, it's simply impossible, no matter what formula you use.